CERRAR UN JDIALOG PRESIONANDO UNA TECLA (ESCAPE)
necesitaría ayuda. El tema es sencillo de explicar, desde un JFrame creo una instancia al jDialog para hacerlo visible. El inconveniente es que necesitaría cerrar ese jDialog pulsando la tecla "ESC" en este caso.
Dejo una parte del código. Saludos
JFRAME:
new verPrecioProducto(this,true).setVisible(true);
JDIALOG:
**
public class cerrarKeyListener implements KeyListener {
        JDialog verPrecioProducto = new JDialog();
        @Override        
        public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {
            throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet.");
        }
        @Override
        public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {            
            if(e.getKeyCode()==KeyEvent.VK_ESCAPE) {
                verPrecioProducto.setVisible(false);
                System.out.println("TECLA ESCAPE");
            }
        }
        @Override
        public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {
            throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet.");
        }    
    }

**
